# Would a polynomial-time algorithm for an NP-hard problem implies that P=NP?

Tags: np-complete, np-hard, np

An NP-hard problem is not in NP. (If it was in NP, it would be an NP-complete problem not NP-hard.)

So my question is: if someone can find a polynomial-time algorithm for an NP-hard problem, would that means that P=NP?

I think yes (I am almost sure) but I can't find the reason why?

Comment: " I can't find the reason why?" Have you tried looking at the definition of NP-hard?

Comment: And you think I did not look for the definition of NP-hard?

Comment: @ Dr W : I know the definition of P, NP, NP-complete and NP hard. The question you put does not answer my question.

Comment: It follows immediately from the definition of NP-hard. A problem is NP hard if it is polytime reducible from every problem in NP. This *literally* means that, if an NP-hard problem is in P, every problem in NP is also in P, because that's what a polynomial time reduction *is*. It's not a theorem that needs to be proved or explained, it is true by definition, which is why we kept pointing you at the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conclusion is correct: Since an NP-complete problem exists that can be reduced to your NP-hard problem, if you should be able to solve your NP-hard problem in polynomial time the NP-complete problem would be in P, hence P=NP.

Comment: If an NP-hard problem is in NP, then why isn't it NP-complete?

Comment: You are right, an NP-hard problem might not be in NP. But it does not need to be, since NP-complete is a subset of NP-hard AFAIK.

Comment: Yeah, this is factually incorrect. An NP-complete problem is in NP by definition, the definition of NP hard is that the problem is polytime reducible to every NP problem.

Comment: @Blid if an NP-hard problem is in NP then it IS NP-complete